# Connect to remote clickhouse db via clickhouse command line

Tags: clickhouse

When I try to connect to remote clickhouse db via clickhouse command line:
`$ clickhouse-client -h some_ip.com --port 8123 -u some_user --password some_password -d some_db`

I get:

> ClickHouse client version 18.12.17.
>   Connecting to database some_db at some_ip.com:8123 as user some_user.
>   Code: 102. DB::NetException: Unexpected packet from server some_ip:8123, another_ip
>   (expected Hello or Exception, got Unknown packet)

However this:
`$ curl http://some_ip.com:8123`
Returns:

> Ok

How to connect to remote clickhouse db via clickhouse command line?

P.S. connection establishes well with IDE such as datagrip but not with ch command-line

Answer (score 20, accepted):

clickhouse-client works with server over TCP which binds on 9000 port, and datagrip works over HTTP protocol with port 8123.

You should:
`$ clickhouse-client -h some_ip.com --port 9000 -u some_user --password some_password -d some_db`